# Decreasing function that aproaches $e$

Tags: limits, eulers-number-e

I need an example of a decreasing function $f(x)$ for which it holds:
$$ \lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = e.$$

Edit: As an answer to the first comment, function $f(x)$ can't use $e$. It should have some nice form like its increasing counterparts:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{x}\frac{1}{i!}$$
or:
$$(1 + 1/x)^x.$$
Comment: By a nice form, I mean using basic operations as in the above expressions.

Comment: You can come up a decreasing function that approaches any number and convert that into a decreasing function approaching Euler’s number, keep that in mind and try to solve your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interesting example is

$$
f(x) = \frac{(x+1)^{x+1}}{x^x} - \frac{x^x}{(x-1)^{x-1}}
$$

It was proved that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = e$ by Harlan J. Brothers and John Knox ([pdf](https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03025225)). Not only is the function decreasing, it also converges much quicker than other functions like $f(x) = \sum^x_{k=1}\frac{1}{k!}$ or even $f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt[x]{x!}}$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x) = (1 - 1/x)^{-x}$ converges to $e$ and is monotonically decreasing.

You are free to add to it any decreasing function that goes to zero, such as $e^{-x}$.